# ramda merging 2 json objects depending on there types

Tags: ramda.js

I need to merge 2 json object when the values are arrays there contents should be concatenated and if the values are primitive type then the value of first object should be taken.

```
R.mergeDeepWith(R.concat,
                { a: true, c: { values: [10, 20], d: { names: ['Alex']} }},
                { a: false, b: true, c: { values: [15, 35] , d: { address: ['Diesel Str 2']}}});
```

Arrays or deep object are working but for the key a I am getting an error.

Comment: nit: JSON objects don't exist. What you have here are plain literal objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do something like this:

```js
const myMerge = mergeDeepWith(
  (a, b) => is (Array) (a) && is (Array) (b) ? concat (a, b) : a)
  
console .log (myMerge (
  {a: true, c: {values: [10, 20]}},
  {a: false, b: true, c: {values: [15, 35]}}
))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {mergeDeepWith, is, concat} = R</script>
```

We use `mergeDeepWith` and then call `concat` if both arguments are arrays, choosing the first one if not.